# How to apply gradient mask on dots

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to apply mask with gradient for all dots on my plot, but not for each dot. That gradient should be changing radial from starting point to maximum point.

Example of what I mean is below, I would like to achieve exactly something similar to that:

[image]

I tried to group all circles like this:

```
 this.svg.append("g").attr('class', 'items-container')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(this.data.suppliers)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr(..) //added proper cx,cy,r so got circles in proper point
```

Then I tried to create gradient:

```
var defs = this.svg.append('defs');

    var gradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
      .attr('x1', '0%')
      .attr('x2', '100%')
      .attr('y1', '0%')
      .attr('y2', '100%');

    gradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('class', 'start')
      .attr('offset', '0%')
      .attr('stop-color', 'red')
      .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

    gradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('class', 'end')
      .attr('offset', '100%')
      .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
      .attr('stop-opacity', 1);
```

And apply it to group:

```
this.svg
  .select('.items-container')
  .style("fill","url(#svgGradient)")
```

But it is not working. Could you please help me here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414159/applying-an-svg-radial-gradient-mask-to-multiple-items?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. As far as I can tell you don't need a `<mask>` or anything like that. All you need is filling the circles according to the carat value, which goes from 0 to 3.

That being said, and since your color sequence is probably [interpolateViridis](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/README.md#interpolateViridis), I suggest you simply use a sequential scale...

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
    .domain([0, 3]);
```

... and fill your circles according to the carat value (here, the `x` property):

```
circleSelection.style("fill", d => colorScale(d.x))
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const data = d3.range(120).map(function(d, i) {
  return {
    y: 14*d3.easeCubic(i/120) + (Math.random()*(6*i/120)),
    x: i / 40
  }
});
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([280, 20])
  .domain([0, 20]);
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([30, 480])
  .domain([0, 3]);
const colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
  .domain([0, 3]);
const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y))
  .style("stroke", "dimgray")
  .style("fill", d => colorScale(d.x));
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,280)")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way round:

1. Create a rectangle with the gradient that has the size of your chart.
2. Create a mask with your circles and apply this mask to the rectangle. If you use white color and fill-opacity < 1 for your circles, this should give exactly the displayed effect.

**Update:** Here is an illustration of my idea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just to need to adjust the definition of your linear gradient so it's defined wrt the canvas not each object - something like

```
var gradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
      .attr('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
      .attr('x1', '100')
      .attr('x2', '600')
      .attr('y1', '100')
      .attr('y2', '600');
```

where the x1, x2 etc. are the coordinates of your chart area